# Insert excluding the second, adding the first from the existing records

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, bulkinsert

I want to find more efficient way than my solution. So here is the problem:
I want to have a bulk insert from a select statement. (Background information: I am using MSSQL 2005)

Example of the select:

```
SELECT number, amount, year, modifiedDate, itm, city, c, d, e, f.... FROM X
JOIN Y ....
```

So if the result is

```
...
Num Amount Year ModifiedDate Itm City ... ...
1   100    2011 01-01-2011   2   Amsterdam .. ..
1   100    2011 01-02-2011   5   Den Haag .. ..
2   4560   2011 01-02-2011   6   Amsterdam .. .. 
33   456    2010 01-02-2011   12  Leiden .. ..
22   456    2010 01-02-2011   12  Leiden .. ..
....
```

In the destination I want to have:

```
...
Num Amount Year ModifiedDate Itm City ... ...
1   100    2011 01-02-2011   5   Den Haag .. ..
2   4560   2011 01-02-2011   6   Amsterdam .. .. 
33   456    2010 01-02-2011   12  Leiden .. ..
22   456    2010 01-02-2011   12  Leiden .. ..
....
```

Without this record: ( 1   100    2011 01-01-2011   2   Amsterdam)

I want to insert the first from these two in a destination table. I have other records coming out of the select that should be inserted as well. So in this case I want to take the first one where number, amount and year are the same order by modifiedDate DESC. That is what I want to do. I already made a solution using Cursor, but there should be a better way.

Comment: I still don't think this is enough information.  Please show your cursor so we can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: The reason I am not posting the cursor is because I am looking for another solution. With cursor I have the answer already. I wonder if there is ANOTHER way. The reason I don't post the whole query is because it is very complex, but that is the idea basically. I think now should be explicit. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Between those two rows, how do you tell the first one from the second one? You are ordering rows by `modifiedDate`, but those two have identical `modifiedDate` values. Their particular order then, in the absence of other sorting criteria, would be arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for all the responses. I got a different idea which is way faster than the old-fashion cursor and I think it matches what I was looking for, so I am sharing it here as well.

```
--Test Data
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime, city nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @destTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime, city nvarchar(100))  

INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, city ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'01 Jan 2011', 'aaa')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, city ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'02 Jan 2011', 'bbb') 
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, city ) VALUES (2,4560,2011,'02 Jan 2011', 'ccc') 
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, city ) VALUES (33,456,2010,'02 Jan 2011', 'ddd') 
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, city ) VALUES (22,456,2010,'02 Jan 2011', 'ddd') 

--Query
INSERT INTO @destTable
SELECT * FROM @sourceTable
WHERE CAST(number AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CAST(amount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CAST(yr AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), modifiedDate,121)
IN
(
SELECT CAST(number AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CAST(amount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CAST(yr AS NVARCHAR(100)) + '_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), MAX(modifiedDate),121)
FROM @sourceTable  
GROUP BY number, amount, yr 
)  
--Results 
SELECT * FROM @destTable
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you closer to what you need:

```
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime, itm int, City varchar(20))
DECLARE @destTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime, itm int, City varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'01-01-2011',2,'Amsterdam')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'01-02-2011',5,'Den Haag')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City ) VALUES (2,4560,2011,'01-02-2011',6,'Amsterdam')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City ) VALUES (33,456,2010,'01-02-2011',12,'Leiden')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City ) VALUES (22,456,2010,'01-02-2011',12,'Leiden')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT number, amount, yr, modifiedDate
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, amount, yr ORDER BY modifiedDate DESC) AS itemRank 

    FROM @sourceTable 
    GROUP BY number, amount, yr, modifiedDate
)
INSERT INTO @destTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate, Itm, City )
SELECT st.number, st.amount, st.yr, st.modifiedDate, st.Itm, st.City 
FROM @sourceTable st
INNER JOIN cte ON st.number = cte.number
AND st.amount = cte.amount
AND st.yr = cte.yr
AND st.modifiedDate = cte.modifiedDate
WHERE itemRank = 1
ORDER BY modifiedDate DESC

SELECT * FROM @destTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, I think you need to group on the first three columns, and select the `MAX` value from the `modifiedDate` column.

Let me know if I have misunderstood.

```
SELECT   
         number, 
         amount,
         year,
         MAX(modifiedDate)
FROM     
         X
GROUP BY
         number, amount, year
```

If you're also looking for help on the `INSERT` part of the query, please give more details on what you're currently doing there.

Comment: Yeah, my explanation wasn't that accurate indeed. I added some dummy columns. The original select is more complex with a lot of columns that aren't the same and some join below. I did try some grouping in the where clause, but I still didn't manage to get what I want.

Comment: You should always post full code where feasible.  That way you're more likely to get the answer you really need, even if it takes people longer to understand!  I assume my answer isn't much help then?

Comment: True, I wanted to make it easier to understand, but I guess that wasn't the case. No, your answer is not what I am looking for. Do you have an idea though? Other than cursor?

Comment: @Ekatarina: If you add a couple more rows of sample input and the output you expect it should make it clear for us.

Comment: @Ekatarina: you are probably looking at some form of recursion...try common table expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by all your columns will acheive this.

Example:

```
--Test Data
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime)
DECLARE @destTable TABLE(number int,amount int, yr int, modifiedDate datetime)

INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'01 Jan 2011')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'01 Jan 2011')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'03 Jan 2011')
INSERT INTO @sourceTable (number, amount, yr, modifiedDate ) VALUES (1,100,2011,'02 Jan 2011')

--Query
INSERT INTO @destTable(number, amount, yr, modifiedDate )
SELECT number, amount, yr, modifiedDate
FROM @sourceTable 
GROUP BY number, amount, yr, modifiedDate
ORDER BY modifiedDate DESC

--Results
SELECT * FROM @destTable
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I edited my question a bit, as it was misleading. I have a huge select, therefor group by doesn't work this way.

Comment: Can you give us the table def for the destination table?